# Does Auto Inflate allow scale down in Event hub?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I am using Azure Event Hub with Auto inflate enabled and max through put selected up to 10. Minimum through put unit is 1.
If ingress traffic increases, Auto Inflate will scale up the throughput unit.
So If ingress traffic goes down in Event hub then Auto Inflate will scale down the throughput unit or not ? 
Please confirm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This feature is a `scale-up only feature`, so it will not automatically scale down the throughput unit.

If you want to scale down, please go to azure portal and [manually update this settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-auto-inflate#enable-auto-inflate-for-an-existing-event-hub).

For more details, please refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-faq#how-does-auto-inflate-feature-of-event-hubs-work).

Comment: What a wasteful feature of Microsoft... all this manual work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Time triggered azure function on a certain period which reduces the capacity (scale down) of all Event Hub namespaces.

[Documentaion](https://tjaddison.com/blog/2019/02/auto-scale-down-all-event-hub-namespaces-with-azure-functions/)